# JQuery equivalent to hide consecutive elements

Tags: jquery, css, hide, rows, css-tables

I'm building an app that needs to hide consecutive rows. Currently I'm using this:

```
#mytable tr.collpaserow + tr,
#mytable tr.collpaserow + tr + tr,
#mytable tr.collpaserow + tr + tr + tr {
display: none;
}
```

This allows me to hide up to 3 more consecutive rows. What I want is to hide all possible consecutive rows no matter what depth with Jquery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you try this?

```
$(".collpaserow").nextAll().hide();
```

http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/

Comment: Does `nextAll()` include nested elements? I though it only includes siblings.

Comment: @François Wahl: that's what `+` selector does, doesn't it?

Comment: @zerkms: Ah, I see. In CSS the `+` is for siblings. I didn't realise that, I thought `+` was for nested element.

Comment: All nested elements: p span - Siblings: p + span - Direct children: p > span